# Magento - Adminhtml - Default website in new customer form

Tags: magento, e-commerce

I am developing an online store for my customer and, we only have one website in our Magento setup.

In the admin panel when I go to Add a customer screen, in the "Associate to Website" field I see "Admin" selected by default. I would like to have my website there by default.

I think one possible way would be to write some code in:
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_Account::initForm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the hint from [Lrrr's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816757/magento-adminhtml-default-website-in-new-customer-form/4925634#4925634) answer and populated the drop-down with only user added websites, that is "Please Select" and "Admin" are no more available as options there by adding the following line:

```
$form->getElement('website_id')->setValues(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/system_store')->getWebsiteValuesForForm());
```

at the end of this function:

```
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_Account::initForm
```

The ideal way would be of course to override the above function in one's own module, but in our case overriding the above class creates conflict for another extension that we have installed, so I took this way round.

Answer (score 5):

The cleanest way to do this is the just set the default value in your database.  This will require no code changes at all.

```
UPDATE eav_attribute
SET default_value = 1
WHERE attribute_code = 'website_id'
```

The sample MySQL statement above sets your default website_id to 1.

Comment: I found this to be a very simple and clean solution for my site.  It doesn't involve any code changes and addresses the OP issue.  The only potential downside is that it doesn't seem you can see/modify this value in the Magento Admin, so in essence it's a "hidden" configuration change, which can make it difficult to have visibility to by other team members.

Comment: Super clean. Thanks!

Comment: CORRECT ANSWER: There is categorically no better answer that this one. This is the only answer that should have been the accepted solution here.

Answer (score 2):

Or You can simply edit array in:

```
Mage_Customer_Model_Customer_Attribute_Source_Website::getAllOptions()
```